# MS SQL SERVER - запросы к БД

Tags: sql-server, linq

Предположим, что есть простейшая таблица в БД, с полями ID, Name. Так же имеется связь с БД через Entity Framework. 
Вопрос: **как правильно** осуществлять выборку и какое **различие в трансляции** *LINQ to SQL* для следующих примеров:

```
...Examples.FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.name.Equals(parameter))
```

и

```
...Examples.Where(ex => ex.name.Equals(parameter)).FirstOrDefault()
```

---

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Example> Examples { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: дак посмотрите лог запросов или в отладчике генерируемый sql код. Скорее всего получите одинаковый результат. На мой взгляд второй вариант куда более нагляден и читаем.

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь даже решарпер, если вы напишите 2 вариант, порекомендует автоматически заменить на первый

Comment: @tCode Возможно. Я не проверял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил и выяснил, что код запроса который генерирует EF в обоих случаях одинаковый.

```
SELECT TOP(1)
 [Extent1].[Id] AS [ID],
 [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
 FROM [dbo].[Examples] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]
```